# How to avoid calling a module from main script requiring change in submodule imports in the module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, dynamic-import, relative-import

Here is a project structure just for demonstrating the actual problem

```
Project/
   +---Scripts/
          +-----module.py
          +-----submodule.py
   +---main.py
```

submodule.py contains

```
def a():
    return "Hello World"
```

module.py contained originally

```
from submodule import a

def f():
    return a()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f())
```

You can see this module.py can also be run as a script(which is important for my project)

But if I write main.py as

```
from Scripts.module import f

print(f())
```

I am getting an error as

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'submodule'

This error generated at module.py, and it is due to the fact that running main.py (instead of module.py changed the import path)

I know, There are two ways to solve it

## Option A:

Change the import in module.py as

`from Scripts.submodule import a`

Now, if I run main.py there are no issues. But if I now run module.py directly I obviously get error as

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Scripts.submodule'

Even though it temporarily solves the problem in main.py, if is still messy, and also both main.py and module.py cannot be run in this method

## Option B:

Use relative import in module.py
`from .submodule import a`

Now also if I run main.py there are no issues. But again if I run module.py directly I get error as

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

**I don't understand what am I doing wrong here. I want to be able to run both main.py and module.py without any code change, so that developers who writes the modules can follow the same convention when importing submodules.**

I also tried to make a `__init__.py` both in Project root folder and also in Scripts folder, but still getting the same error when running module.py individually.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/407651 (and many other questions too).

Comment: Making a module also be a script is fundamentally broken (because then it’s `__main__` rather than the module it is otherwise).  It’s not an answer to your question, but it’s not worth fixing this (in the long term).

Comment: In Option B, it works if you run `python -m Scripts.module` (instead of `python Scripts/module.py`).

Answer (score 0):

I assumed `submodule.py` to be like this (because it is not true in the current state!):

```py
# submodule.py

def a():
    return 'hello'
```

Then I changed `module.py` like this:

```py
# module.py

from Scripts.submodule import a
   
   ...
```

It works properly!

Comment: I already mentioned that in Option A. If in module.py I write "from Scripts.submodule import a" then I cannot run module.py as a script. I want to be able to run main.py as well as module.py as a script without any code change.